# return undefined on div

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest

Here i'm attempting to load a form using ajax and set to "maindiv" upon clicking a button "Add Item".but returns undefined. A servlet named "AddItem" also exists..

```
 html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="button" onclick="loadAddItemForm()" value="Add Item"/>
    <div id="maindiv"> </div>

<script>
    function loadAddItemForm() {
        var x;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        x.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                //
                var txt = "ItemCode:" + "<input type='text' id='itemcodetxt'><br>" + "ItemName:" + "<input type='text' id='itemnametxt'><br>" + "Description:" + "<input type='text' id='descriptiontxt'><br>" + "QtyOnHand:" + "<input type='text' id='qtyonhandtxt'><br>" + "Reorderlevel:" + "<input type='text' id='reorderleveltxt'><br>" + "Unit price:" + "<input type='text' id='unitpricetxt'><br><input type='button' value='Add' onclick='addItem()'/>";
            }
            document.getElementById("maindiv").innerHTML = txt;

        };
        x.open("GET", "AddItem", true);
        x.send();

    }

</script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Put `document.getElementById("maindiv").innerHTML = txt;` inside the if condition after `var txt = "ItemCode:" ...`

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Answer (score -1):

You're not passing in the page, try

```
 x.open("GET", "AddItem.html", true);
```

assuming that's the page you waant to open.

it's returning false because it's looking for AddItem, and as it's returning false the txt is undefined as the if block isn't executed

Comment: Why would you have to put `.html` in the URL to the servlet?